# Selenium Testng click on text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, testng

i learned alot when i was using selenium IDE, but now i want to learn more about selenium testng and trying to code to open a page and click on a button
it opens firefox but isnt clicking on desired link.

`www.otelo.de` i am trying to click on "Tarife"

```
@BeforeTest /*Set Path to Firefox and launch Browser*/
public void launchBrowser()
{  
      System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Users\\wonttellthemachinemyname\\Desktop\\Selenium\\Firefox\\FirefoxPortable.exe");
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
      driver.get(baseUrl);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void verifyHomepageTitle() 
{
     driver.findElement(By.text("Tarife")).click();
}
```

i cant find button id but it should work with find

what am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no function in By named text(). For accessing a link by Text you should use either of these functions:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tarife"));
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Tarife"));
```

Also, be very specific about the case of the text.

You need to learn more about ways to locate elements in Selenium Web Driver.
Here is a useful link: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators

Comment: i tryed both what u posted, but it still only opens ff and does nothing afterwards....

Comment: i really tryed every single one from your link it still is not clicking on that "Tarife"

Comment: I believe you already have the website url passed through your variable 'baseUrl'. Note that, if you are getting the landing page of Firefox and it's not even opening the link. This is probably an issue with your older version of selenium jar.

Comment: If you are able to launch the page. Inspect your element, make sure it is in <a> tag or else post that complete tag here.

Comment: <a onclick="this.blur();" class="submenu produkte sibling first" href="https://www.otelo.de/handytarife/index.html" btattached="true">Tarife</a>       inspected with firebug .... nothing is working not with class not with text....

Comment: could make it work WITH  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class = 'submenu produkte sibling first']")).click();   but cant i do it with class or text?  thx for help

Comment: Great, One more point to Add. Sometimes we see a difference between casing of text between what is in the tag and what actually is displayed. So, if your browser displays text as "TARIFE" use the same casing to find text.

Comment: yes i understand you....  BUT i tried   driver.findElement(By.linkText("TARIFE"));
  driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("TARIFE"));      too, and it just doesnt work only with xpath... and i dont know why.... :/ THX

Answer (score 0):

just do it:

```
 driver.get("http://www.otelo.de");        

 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 Thread.sleep(5000);  //try to use explicit wait here
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".submenu.produkte.sibling.first>a")).click();
```

Comment: THX you very much, very good method.... but do you know why i cant open it with class or textlink? thx you very much :D

Comment: actually there's a lot of method u can use to find ur element. prateek send u an important link and google is also there for u. just go through the documents and u can understand everything.Finally i think u can accept the answer.

Comment: yes they helped me alot, but still i was just curious how to make it work with textlink or byclass.... dunno why u are that aggressive